# In-App payment in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am developing an application that has some digital contents like image,audio etc is there. I need to implement the In-App payment in the application so that users can purchase the content and enjoy it. How do i implement it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you find a particular response helpful, please consider upvoting it. If a particular response answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the android documentation on [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the Android In-app Billing sample application and modify the code to make it work in your app:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html